# Show that $\lim \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int_0^1f$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

I want to show that if $f$ is integrable on the interval $[0,1]$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int_0^1f$.

I am using the definition of integrability in the sense of Riemann-Stieltjes:

$$\forall\epsilon>0:\exists P:\forall Q\geq P:\left|S(Q_n,f,I)-\int_0^1f\right|<\epsilon$$

Where $P$ and $Q$ are partitions of $[0,1]$.

I thought about using the definition for the partitions:

$$Q_n=\left(0,\frac1n,\frac2n,\cdots,\frac{n-1}n,1\right)$$
$$c_k=\frac kn$$

Then we have:

$$\left|S(Q_n,f,I)-\int_0^1f\right|=\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac kn\right)-\int_0^1f\right|$$

The problem is that I don't know how I can show that this tends to zero since a $P$ appears in the definition of integral and I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: The sum does not make sense when $k>n$. The upper limit in sum should be $n$ instead of $\infty$ and then the result follows by definition of Riemann integral.

Comment: You're right, I was wrong when I wrote the limits.

I fixed it.

Comment: The duplicate does not really resolve this question. The answer there just restates that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$ because $f$ is Riemann integrable.  The question here has to do with the equivalence of two definitions of Riemann integrability.  OP works with the definition based on the existence for any $\epsilon$ of a partition $P_\epsilon$ such that all Riemann sums $S(Q,f)$ are within $\epsilon$ of the integral when $Q$ is a "refinement" of $P_\epsilon$ ...

Comment: The other definition states that $S(P,f) \to \int_0^1 f $ as $\|P\| \to 0$, i.e., the partition norm tends to zero.  In effect what is being asked is why are these definitions equivalent. That must be proved and the proof is not entirely trivial.

Comment: @RRL the question starts with "I want to show that if $f$ is integrable on the interval $[0,1]$ then ...". Integrability is given. So, it applies to **all partitions** satisfying the definition(s). $Q_n$ can be constructed to satisfy the definition(s), thus it becomes a particular case.

Comment: Integrability with the definition given as $\forall\epsilon>0:\exists P:\forall Q\geq P:\left|S(Q_n,f,I)-\int_0^1f\right|<\epsilon$ and $Q\geq P$ means $Q$ is a refinement of $P$.  With that as the definition you don't have immediately that a sum converges to the integral just because the norm converges to zero.  It is intuitively obvious and it is true but it is not just a trivial consequence of the first definition,   $Q$ refines $P$ means that every point in $P$ is also in $Q$.  For uniform partitions $P_m$ is not necessarily a refinement of $P_n$ when $m > n$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1618326/148510) for example.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. I have to use the definition of integral with partitions and refinements.

Comment: @RRL, anyway, [showing the equivalence of the two definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_integral) sounds too complicated for this exercise, imho.

Comment: My problem is that $P$ could be any kind of partition and so I don't have $Q_n$ to be a refinement.

Comment: @Pentachito, two definitions are equivalent (see the wiki link and the proof there). I'd choose the easiest one for the problem.

Comment: Actually the only thing I want I have to show is:

Comment: $\forall\epsilon>0:\exists P:\forall Q\geq P:|S(Q, f, I)-\int_{[a,b]}f|<\epsilon$ implies $\forall\epsilon>0:\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\geq N:|S(Q_n, f, I)-\int_{[a,b]}f|<\epsilon$

Comment: @rtybase: I agree -- if you are allowed to use either definition then this becomes a simple, almost trivial, problem where $\|P_n\| = 1/n \to 0$ implies $S(P_n,f) \to \int_0^1 f$ by definition.

Comment: Duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3940980/f-riemann-integrable-on-0-1/3941014#3941014  ?